# mootools clone() inject('top') reverses the element order order

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

Using clone(rue, false).inject('myList', 'top') reverses the item order when 'top'is the where string. There must be a elegant way of sorting this? is my approach wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-gb" xml:lang="en-gb">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/moo.1.4.5/core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEvent('domready', function () {


            $('myList').getChildren().each( function (el, i)  { 
                el.clone(true, false).addClass('clone').inject('myList', 'top');
                el.clone(true, false).addClass('clone').inject('myList', 'bottom');
            }) ;


        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="myList">
        <li><p>Slide 1</p></li>
        <li><p>Slide 2</p></li>
        <li><p>Slide 3</p></li>
        <li><p>Slide 4</p></li>
        <li><p>Slide 5</p></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

returns

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li class="clone"><p>Slide 3</p></li>
    <li class="clone"><p>Slide 2</p></li>
    <li class="clone"><p>Slide 1</p></li>
    <li><p>Slide 1</p></li>
    <li><p>Slide 2</p></li>
    <li><p>Slide 3</p></li>
    <li class="clone"><p>Slide 1</p></li>
    <li class="clone"><p>Slide 2</p></li>
    <li class="clone"><p>Slide 3</p></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on your objective. if your aim is to clone the list and inject it at the top, you can do this along your current line of thinking:

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/xNWrM/

```
var list = $('myList'),
    lis = list.getElements('li');

lis.reverse().each(function(el){
    el.clone(true, true).addClass('clone').inject(list, 'top');
});
```

there may be a more elegant way to clone them by injecting after the previously injected element as you loop them, this will save the Elements.reverse call.

Comment: Thank you .reverse() is probably going to be very usefull, im still going to need to lst.each() twice though..

Answer (score 0):

look at what you're doing... `inject('top')`. the top of the list is always the same position - the top of the list.

e.g

```
1 2 3         <--original
1 1 2 3       <--clone 1 + insert top
2 1 1 2 3     <--clone 2 + insert top
3 2 1 1 2 3   <--clone 3 + insert top
```

you'd have to start at the END of the chunk you want to clone, and work your way backwards:

```
1 2 3         <--original
3 1 2 3       <--clone 3 + insert top
2 3 1 2 3     <--clone 2 + insert top
1 2 3 1 2 3   <--clone 1 + insert top
```

Comment: Yes Marc I understand the reason, I'm just struggling work out a elegant way of reversing $('myList'). thanks for your help Dimitar has offered this below.